# Weblogic Server PermGen errors

Tags: weblogic, application-server, weblogic11g, oracle-fusion-middleware

When I created datasource and tried to attach to target server, I am getting the following errors, where do I need to increase space in Weblogic 10.3.6? Any help is highly appreciable

> Console encountered the following error 
>       weblogic.application.WrappedDeploymentException: PermGen space at
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) at 
>       java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) at 
>       java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) at 
>       java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) at 
>       java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) at 
>       java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at
>       java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>       java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at 
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) at 
>       sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) at 
>       oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIdcb.fillupAccessors(T4CTTIdcb.java:399) at 
>       oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIdcb.receiveCommon(T4CTTIdcb.java:208) at 
>       oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIdcb.receive(T4CTTIdcb.java:146) at 
>       oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.readDCB(T4C8Oall.java:844) at
>       oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:358) at 
>       oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192) at
>       oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) at

Comment: Have you edited setDomainEnv.sh to increase MaxPermSize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PermGen Space Out-of-Memory Error when Using the Sun JDK

Bug: 8589284
Added: 06-May-2011
Platform: All

When the Sun JDK is used as the JVM for the SOA managed server, Oracle recommends that the following memory settings be used. If proper memory settings are not used, repeated operations on task detail applications (human workflow) can result in PermGen space out-of-memory errors.

For:

For UNIX operating systems, open the $DOMAIN_HOME/bin/setSOADomainEnv.sh file.

For Windows operating systems, open the DOMAIN_HOME\bin\setSOADomainEnv.cmd file.

Increase the following values:

PORT_MEM_ARGS="${PORT_MEM_ARGS} -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when running WLS as a Windows service, even after setting MEM_ARGS properly in my service creation script.  I finally resolved it by updating a few Windows registry entries:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\wlsvc yerdomain_yerserver\Parameters]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\services\wlsvc yerdomain_yerserver\Parameters]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\wlsvc yerdomain_yerserver\Parameters]

Not sure why there were 3 entries, but after updating those all and restarting the service everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

You should do what @better_user_mkstemp said, but also I can't help myself from noticing that you have a serious problem with your DataSource, an Oracle DataSource to be specific, try to  go to 
`http://your_server:7001/console/dashboard`and start monitoring your Data Sources and see which one is this, and try tune it using [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13737/ds_tuning.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was to edit the `DOMAIN\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd` file. The following modifications were made before the server would start as intended:

- The `-Xms` and `-Xmx` values were increased
- the `-XX:PermSize` and `-XX:MaxPermSize` values were increased too

and lastly, but probably most importantly

- the `if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Sun" (` conditions were changed to `if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Oracle" (` in order to properly recognize my JVM.

Before this last modification the memory changes were only partly reflected to the initialised JVM, and this meant that the parameters regarding the PermGen Space were simply ignored.

Comment: I will try this approach.